# dllexported appended string is corrupt

Tags: c++, string, debugging, dllimport, dllexport

i have an exe loading a dll. i wrote both.

i am dllexporting a function foo that returns a std::wstring.

all it does is say

std::wstring blah = L"rgjwgfw";

```
  return blah.append(L"hey");
```

in the exe where i import foo, the string is corrupt. as soon as i return from the function where i call foo i get failed assertions. sometimes i get a message saying Windows has triggered a breakpoint in foo.exe. this may be due to a corruption of the heap, etc..... This may also be due to a user pressing f12 while foo.exe has focus. etc....

any idea why this happens? it doesn't happen if i remove the append line from foo and jsut return the original string, there are no problems.

thanks

Comment: are you sure that both dlls are compiled with the same options (release or debug)? STL templates may have different sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty common problem. You need to link both the DLL and the executable to use the standard library in a DLL. That way they share a common copy of the standard library a common heap. Otherwise, you end up with code in the executable trying to use one heap, and code in the DLL using a separate heap. When you pass almost anything that uses dynamic allocation across the boundary, each assumes the dynamically allocated buffer in the object came from its own heap. Almost any manipulation can not only corrupt the object, but also the entire heap.

Comment: i can't do that because i am linking against mfc statically. using the dll runtime lib requires dynamically linking against mfc. 
is there a way to do this without making the function the kind of function you call twice? Once to get the length of the buffer, and then another time to actually fill the buffer with the data?

Comment: I suspect about all you can do at that point is use a different string class that has all its code in the DLL (the problem arises largely because the allocator is a template argument, so the instantiation in the executable and the DLL are separate).